# Django "writer.writerow" for each column

Tags: django, csv

I am trying to get each column separately. But I still can't get the right division. My code is added below. I tried to apply a loop, change the format of the list but to no avail.

I was looking for answers in the forum, but the code below doesn't work for me at all.

```
#My try
wr.writerow(item)  #column by column (everything goes to one column)
wr.writerows(item) #row by row (divides my word into parts)


def export_users_csv(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="users.csv"'

    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerows(('Id', 'Username', 'Email', 'Password'))


    users = CustomUser.objects.all().values_list('id', 'username', 'email', 'password')
    for user in users:
        writer.writerow(user)

    return response
```

**Expectations**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You here use [**`writerows`** [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) instead of [**`writerow`** [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow). So the csv writer will interpret `'Id'`, and `'username'` as two (individual) rows:

```
writer.writerow(('Id', 'Username', 'Email', 'Password'))
users = CustomUser.objects.all().values_list('id', 'username', 'email', 'password')
writer.writerows(users)
```

Note that one normally does *not* use `.values_list()` or `.values()` to serialize data. Normally it is better to use a serializer, since that makes it easier to make *bidirectional* serializing/parsing and furthermore add extra logic how to serialize.